# indefinite integral with noninteger radical in denominator

Tags: integration

I tried to use substitution and the power rule to no avail.  How should I go about finding the integral of this?

${dy\over (x^2+y^2)^\frac 3 2 }$

The book I'm reading gives the answer but I want to know how to work it myself (not look it up in table).

${y\over x^2(x^2+y^2)^\frac 1 2 }$

Thank you,
relayman357

SOLUTION:

Let y = x $\tan u$ 
u = $\arctan (y/x)$ 
$dy/du=x (sec u)^2$ 
 
$\int {x (sec^2 u) du\over [x^2+x^2 (tan^2 u)]^\frac 3 2 }$ 
 
$\int {x (sec^2 u) du\over x^3[1+tan^2 u]^\frac 3 2 }$ 
 
$\int {sec^2 u du\over x^2[sec^2u]^\frac 3 2 }$ 
 
 
$\int {sec^2 u du\over x^2[sec^3u]}$ 
 
 
$1/x^2\int {du\over sec u }$ 
 
 
$1/x^2\int {(cosu) du }$ 
 
 
$1/x^2 sin (u)$ 
 
Undoing the substitution and using the right-triangle relationships: 
$1\over x^2 sin(arctan (y/x))$ 
 
$y\over x^2(x^2+y^2)^\frac 1 2$

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $y=x\sinh(t)$, leading to $dy = x \cosh(t)\,dt$?

Comment: No, I will see what I can do with your suggestion.  By the way, why doesn't simple substitution work?  e.g.  u = ${(x^2+y^2)^\frac 3 2 }
$

Comment: It turns out that if i had a "y" in the numerator i could have solved this with simple "u" substitution.  e.g. ${y\over (x^2+y^2)^\frac 3 2 }$ can be easily solved with u = ${(x^2+y^2)}$.   How do we know when that will work - are there any rules or guidelines?

Answer (score 0):

Take $$x^2+y^2=y^2\left(\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^2+1\right)$$ and substitute $$\frac{x}{y}=t$$

Comment: Thank you.  I will start looking at your suggestion.

Comment: If someone could point me to some information I'd like to learn about the methods suggested here.  I'm a long way from a math major.